# Ubuntu doesn't recognize my USB

Tags: usb

I create yesterday a live-USB from Ubuntu 14-04 and everything worked fine.Then I also installed another distibution of Linux on the same USB,and now neither Ubuntu nor Windows doesn't recognize my USB

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have tried [formatting the usb drive](http://www.wikihow.com/Format-a-USB-Flash-Drive-in-Ubuntu)?

The next step would be trying

```
lsusb
```

in the terminal to see if your computer is detecting it.

If your drive shows up, [try mounting it manually](http://linuxconfig.org/howto-mount-usb-drive-in-linux).

If you are unable to format it, and lsusb does not detect it, I am afraid your drive may be toast.